# "Syntactic Sugar" for setting object property, if the value is truthy

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I don't know if this exists or not but in my project I have a lot of parsing and validating. I end of with 5-10+ lines of `if(value) object.value = value`.

I could go the route of `object.value = value || (your favorite falsy value)` BUT then the object has a property of a falsy value.

I.e. (this is not production code just to give you an idea of what i'm talking about)

```
let filter = {}

let thing = ctx.query.thing

thing = Validation.validateThingy(thing)

if(thing) filter.thing = thing

// +50 more param parsing/request body parsing

return DB.find(filter).then(etc...)
```

Does anyone know of a more elegant way to do something like this, without doing an `||` or looping over the object's properties and filtering out the falsy values?

Comment: the shortcut evaluation in [chad's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43376568/1084004) gets my vote, but if you don't like it, how about: `object.value = value || object.value`

Comment: @mikeapr4 That would set the value of `object.value` to `undefined` and the object would now have a key of `value`. Also it's the first caveat in the question.

Comment: Incorrect - see https://jsfiddle.net/ps7zf4my/

Comment: Oh wait, I see, `object.value` doesn't have a value to begin with, nm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function for it, with an object, key and value.

```
function setValue(object, key, value) {
    if (value) {
        object[key] = value;
    }
}

// usage
let filter = {};

setValue(filter, 'thing', Validation.validateThingy(ctx.query.thing));
```

Or you could move the validation part inside of the function

```
function setValue(object, key) {
    var value = Validation.validateThingy(ctx.query[key])
    if (value) {
        object[key] = value;
    }
}

// usage
let filter = {};

setValue(filter, 'thing');
```

Comment: Yeah, I like that. Nothing built into JS though huh?

Comment: actually no, as i know.

Comment: @JamesKenaley: Those are about your choices: The object properties loop you don't want to do, a utility function like this one, or (ab)using `&&` as [chad_ flags up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43376568/157247). But the `&&` is basically just an `if` in silly clothing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could abuse short circuit evaluation of `&&` and say `thing && (filter.thing = thing)` but it'd be uglier than what you have imo.  I think either what you have or an abstracted function would be better options.

Comment: If you read [Doug Crockford's Javascript, The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) he makes a strong case against using things like this.  Just because you *can* do it, doesn't mean you should.  Anyone who comes along and reads the code would have to think about it for a second, I think.  At least at first.

Comment: A quarter of my upvote is for the answer, the other three quarters for the caveats on using it. :-)

Comment: This does answer the question, and if I had enough rep to upvote, I would. Going with the function, though!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
   thing && (filter.thing = thing);
```

Answer (score 0):

**My bad**, the OP clearly said:

> ...without doing an || or looping over the object's properties and filtering out the falsy values?

...I just missed it. The below does exactly that.

For future readers who don't have the OP's preference:

---

You could collect the values in an object, then use a utility function to loop through those values and only copy the truthy ones:

```
let values = {};
values.thing = Validation.validateThingy(ctx.query.thing);
// +50 others...
let filter = copyTruthy({}, values);
return DB.find(filter).then(/*etc...*/);
```

where `copyTruthy` is:

```
function copyTruthy(dest, source) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(source)) {
        if (source[key]) {
            dest[key] = source[key];
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that but that would add too much overhead, also I added this solution to the bottom of the question, as not what I'd like to do. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @JamesKenaley: Er, um, that's what I get for failing to read closely... *sigh* My bad.

Comment: @JamesKenaley: I wonder about the overhead, though, on a JavaScript engine with optimized `for-of`, compared with all those function calls in Nina's (excellent) solution, if overhead is a bit issue...

Comment: @TJCrowder: not really the performance overhead, but the code overhead of doing a sync for-loop for every request. Just a matter of preference.

Comment: @JamesKenaley: I'm not following you. You do the 50+ assignments without ifs, and then make a single function call to your utility function at the end. What code overhead?

Comment: @TJCrowder: o_o Touche. When it comes down to it, I just don't personally like this approach as a code preference. I'd much rather go with a Util function that does what @nina-scholz (and others) suggested. `Util.set(filter, 'thing', value)` etc... This question was about code style more then anything else, "Does anyone know of a more elegant way to do something like this...". As for performance, I think your solution might be faster.

Comment: @JamesKenaley: Fair enough! And FWIW, I'm quite sure that I did something almost exactly like Nina's solution on a project just late last year (rather than the above, which IIRC would also have solved the same problem). Nina's is the simple and direct approach. I'm not sure why I didn't think of it reading your question, but I'm glad she did.

Answer (score 0):

Using a ternary expression as a standalone statement will work.

`value ? (object.value = value) : null;`